# How do I fix the over 80 characters checkstyle error?

Tags: java, checkstyle

```
  alert.setHeaderText(String.format(
                                     //this line//"Title:%s%nSinger:%s%nDate:%s%nAlbum:%s%nSongs:%s%nResult: %s",
                                      msg.getTitle(), msg.getSinger(),
                                      msg.getDate(), msg.getAlbum(),
                                      msg.getResult()));
```

I'm trying to fix this checkstyle error. Please help!!!

Comment: Break up the string so that it's on multiple lines. Also you don't need to indent so much on the continuation lines there.

Comment: When I tried to break up the string so it's on multiple line, it has this exception java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:

Comment: What's the actual Checkstyle error you're having?

Comment: Line is longer than 80 characters (found 138).

Comment: Why not just configure check style to ignore literal strings?

Answer (score 1):

in order to fix this checkstyle error you can just break up this line into two lines like this

```
alert.setHeaderText(String.format(
                                     "Title:%s%nSinger:%s%n" +
                                     "Date:%s%nAlbum:%s%nSongs:%s%nResult: %s",
                                      msg.getTitle(), msg.getSinger(),
                                      msg.getDate(), msg.getAlbum(),
                                      msg.getResult()));
```

you should consider just and overall reduction in the indentation level, for example...

```
alert.setHeaderText(String.format(
     "Title:%s%nSinger:%s%n" +
     "Date:%s%nAlbum:%s%nSongs:%s%nResult: %s",
     msg.getTitle(), msg.getSinger(),
     msg.getDate(), msg.getAlbum(),
     msg.getResult()));
```